# Error handling with if statement

Tags: java

This is to validate my GUI input and make sure the user can not enter values out of range

I'm trying to handle this exception with if statement but I'm still printing the red error message. I just want the "Value out of range" message to be printed. I don't want those red exceptions error in my console. Please help or advise. Any other way to handle this can is fine with me.

```
    if (totalTimeToTakeOff <= 0 || totalTimeToLand <= 0 || arrivalRate < 0
                    || arrivalRate > 1 || departureRate < 0 || departureRate > 1
                    || remaingFuel <= 0 || numOfRunways <= 0 || sIMULATION_TIME < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values out of range");

            }
```

Comment: The "red exceptions" message you're seeing has less to do with the code you've posted, and much more to do with how you're handling the exception in the code that calls the above code. Consider catching this and then dealing with it as you feel appropriate. My own view is that it's best to avoid mixing GUI and console code, that any caught exceptions should either notify the user in the GUI or be logged, but not output via standard out.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. Do you want something like this `System.err.println("Values out of range");`?

Comment: As a matter of form, since many of those variables appear to be float/double values, the associated comparands should be expressed as float -- eg, `1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are doing here is creating a new IllegalArgumentException object, and then this method throws this exception. When you throw an exception, the part of your code that calls this method has to handle that exception OR those 'red lines' (the stack trace, basically) are printed. So, for a simple example, say that you have the method `divide()`

```
public double divide(double a, double b){
    if(b==0){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisor cannot be 0");
    }
    return a/b;
}
```

Now, when some other part of your code calls this method, you can choose to handle the IllegalArgumentException that is thrown by this method.

```
 try{
     double c = divide(a,b);
 }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    //put whatever code you want here
 }
```

If you don't catch the exception, then your code breaks and the stack trace (the red text) is printed out. So in other words, your code is functioning as intended; that section of code throws an IllegalArgumentException under some circumstance, and the code that calls that method does not catch the exception and handle it (for example by printing out the message about the exception).

Also, just a minor note- an error in java is different from an exception. An error signifies a process from which the program cannot recover, and an error cannot be caught. Exceptions (all classes that subclass the Exception class) can be caught. An exception can either be checked or unchecked - checked exceptions MUST be caught via a catch statement, whereas unchecked exceptions don't. An example of a checked exception is the IOException, whereas an example of an unchecked exception is the IllegalArgumentException you have displayed here.

One more thing- exceptions are meant to signify an abnormality in your code. If this IllegalArgumentException was thrown from say, a class constructor or a method that can be used for many general purposes, then it makes sense to throw it. However, if that method exists *solely* for the purpose of checking whether input is valid, then have it return a boolean value (true or false) rather than throwing an exception.

One other reason to this is because exception handling tends to be rather slow in comparison to simply returning a true or a false.

Comment: thank you so much you make it clear.. you save my time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) please look into it.

Basic understanding is

```
try { 
   //Something that can throw an exception.
} catch (Exception e) {
  // To do whatever when the exception is caught.
}
```

There is also an finally block which will always be execute even if there is an error. it is used like this

```
try { 
   //Something that can throw an exception.
} catch (Exception e) {
  // To do whatever when the exception is caught & the returned.
} finally {
  // This will always execute if there is an exception or no exception.
}
```

InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

So you would need to catch exceptions like

```
try { 
   rows=scan.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  // When the InputMismatchException is caught.
  System.out.println("The next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  // When the NoSuchElementException is caught.
  System.out.println("Input is exhausted");
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // When the IllegalStateException is caught.
  System.out.println("Scanner is close");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check the values without throwing an exception

```
if (!checkValues())
    System.out.println("Values out of range");
```

Comment: @downvoter are you suggesting that it would be bad form to not throw the exception?

Comment: well like @ElvenAshwin says, exception handling can be slow. So I'd maybe just do a simple check in an if statement. Also, I'd extract the if condition into another method like checkValues(). This means it's easier to read and you won't need to retype all of the conditions if you want to check the values again

Answer (score 0):

You could just print to the console and exit Java (instead of throwing an exception), as that is what an Exception does in essence.

```
System.out.println("Values out of range");
System.exit(0);
```

Alternatively, catch the exception when calling the method

```
try{
    if(checkValues())
    ...
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Values out of range");
}
```